# Manter objeto na memória após fim do método

Tags: c#

Preciso carregar duas planilhas para gerar um dicionário com os dados da planilha.

Estou um pouco confuso em relação a isso.. Eu criei um método LerArquivo para não repetir o código, já que o processo é igual para os dois arquivos.
Este método retorna um dicionário com os dados.

```
public object LerPlanilha(string range, FileInfo planilha)
{

            using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(planilha))
            {
                var worksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets[1];


                var cells = worksheet.Cells;
                var dictionary = cells[range]
                    .GroupBy(c => new { c.Start.Row, c.Start.Column })
                    .ToDictionary(
                        rcg => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(rcg.Key.Row, rcg.Key.Column),
                        rcg => cells[rcg.Key.Row, rcg.Key.Column].Value);

                return dictionary;
            }
}
```

Preciso chamar duas vezes em dois botões diferentes, para carregar os dados de uma planilha por vez, no btnModelo atribuo o retorno de LerArquivo na variável global CelulasCarregadasModelo que é um object.
Estou fazendo dessa forma

```
private void btnModelo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var arquivo = CarregarArquivo().ToString();

            if (arquivo != "OK")
            {

                var planilhaBase = new FileInfo(arquivo);
                CelulasCarregadasModelo =  LerPlanilha("B16:AG16", planilhaBase);

                lblModeloCarregado.Visible = true;
                lblModeloNome.Visible = true;
                lblModeloCarregado.Text = "Planilha Carregada";
                lblModeloNome.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(arquivo);
            }

            else
            {
                lblModeloCarregado.Visible = true;
                lblModeloCarregado.Text = "Erro/Modelo não selecionado";
            }
}
```

E no outro botão btnPlan atribuo o retorno de LerArquivo em CelulasCarregadasPlan

```
private void btnPlan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    var arquivo = CarregarArquivo().ToString();

                    if (arquivo != "OK")
                    {

                        var planilhaBase = new FileInfo(arquivo);
                        CelulasCarregadasPlan = LerPlanilha("B16:AG16", planilhaBase);

                        lblFluxoIntCarregado.Visible = true;
                        lblFluxoIntNome.Visible = true;
                        lblFluxoIntCarregado.Text = "Planilha Carregada";
                        lblFluxoIntNome.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(arquivo);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        lblFluxoIntCarregado.Visible = true;
                        lblFluxoIntCarregado.Text = "Erro/Modelo não selecionado";
                    }
    }
```

Tudo ocorre sem problemas, a variável é preenchida com o dicionário.

O que ocorre é que as variáveis são limpas após o termino do método do botão, não consigo deixá-las carregadas para depois comparar os dois dicionários em um outro método.

Comment: Cara, é só declarar as variáveis fora dos métodos.

Comment: @jbueno Mas as variáveis CelulasCarregadasModelo  e CelulasCarregadasPlan não estão sendo declaradas dentro do método. eu declaro elas depois de public Form1()

Comment: Então tem algo errado com teu código ou com tua explicação. Em que momento que as variáveis perdem o valor? Como você sabe que elas tiveram valor em algum momento?

Comment: Pelo visto você está usando web forms, acredito que seu problema seja o postback, cada botão faz um postback certo? Se for isso, você vai ter que persistir essa variável em algum lugar para recuperar no segundo postback, seja sessão, viewsate ou context.

Comment: É web ou desktop?